# What does "Laundry doesn’t fold itself" mean?

Tags: meaning

> What does "Laundry doesn’t fold itself" mean?

I can't understand it through the literal meaning. Google search return no useful information.

Thank you!

Comment: It means that somebody (either the person speaking or the person they're speaking to) needs to hurry up and start folding the laundry because it isn't magically going to start folding itself. The phrasing that I would expect to hear is "That laundry isn't going to fold itself". You can use similar phrasing for most chores: "That car isn't going to wash itself" or "That grass isn't going to mow itself".

Comment: This is an idiomatic phrase. It is a way of saying things don't get done by themselves. It can be said to someone who is trying to get out of doing something (for example lazy children).

Comment: It means your mother doesn't live there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means *something* will not happen all by itself, that an effort needs to be made/used to make something happen

> the laundry won't fold itself
>   the essay won't write itself
>   dinner won't cook itself
>   the question won't answer itself